# What is the best method to use cache when we have to retrieve data for date range

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have to prepare set of large reports which handle number of table joins and grouping conditions. So loading of this report is pretty slow. Current method of doing this is retrieving retrieving total set of data without joins or grouping and do those functions using code(calculations and arrays)

ex:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $days_in_month; $i++):
    $date = "$year_info-$month_info-$i";
    $date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
    if ($weighted_date == $date1):
        $field_kg[$field_id][$date1] = $cash_kilo + $field_cash_kg[$field_id][$date1];
        if ($plantation_id == 2) {
            $cas_nor_kg[$field_id][$date1] = $field_cash_kg[$field_id][$date1] + $field_kg[$field_id][$date1];
        } else {
            $cas_nor_kg[$field_id][$date1] = $field_kg[$field_id][$date1];
        }
        $cas_nor_kg[$field_id][$date1] = $field_cash_kg[$field_id][$date1];
        $field_round[$field_id][$date1] = $round_number;
    endif;
endfor;
```

So as you can see this makes code hard to read. So is there a method to use cache in these kind of scenarios and how?

Comment: Dealing with joins and very slow data processing, my approach is by creating an temporary table that will save all calculation. To fill this table, I create a cron job/queue so it will updated at certain time. So while displaying the data, basicly I just need to select / filter because the calculation process has been done before. Oh, I forgot. Indexing your column will give big performance.

Comment: If this is faster than your database query, then there IS DEFINITLY something wrong with your database server

Comment: Any possible reason @Philipp?

Comment: Maybe missing indizies - can't tell you without the query and database structure